How to use -copyts with between?
I'm using enable=between(t,0,5) with ffmpeg to apply a filter during only part of a video, but when I add -copyts to maintain the timestamps in the file, then it extends the length of the output based on the PTS of the input and causes playback issues.
I've also tried filtering by frames using enable=between(n,0,150) but the same problem happens.
Is there a way to still use -copyts without it extending the beginning like this?
Here's an example command:
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i overlay1.svg -i overlay2.svg -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=10:10:enable='between(n,0,150)'[v0];[v0][2:v]overlay=10:10:enable='between(t,150,1200)" -c:v libx264 -copyts -muxdelay 0 output.mp4


Share your full command.

I added an example command to the question

That command should result in an output equal to the length of input.mp4. How long is the actual output?

The length of the actual data is the same (i.e. the number of frames is the same and ffprobe says that it's the same length), but when I play it in QuickTime or VLC then it say it's an hour long.
QuickTime starts at the beginning of the time and there's an hour of black that I have to scroll through before the actual video starts.
VLC shows all of that time but starts playing the video and shows it scrolled through that hour.

Add -avoid_negative_ts make_zero before output.mp4 and check.

Adding -avoid_negative_ts before the first -i and before output.mp4 doesn't change the output and it's byte for byte identical.

Also add -map_chapters -1 -dn -sn

I upgraded to 7.1 and between using n now works
